# Sumar datos de una tabla sql cuando le envio parametros desde otra pagina

Tags: php, sql

En mi index hago un include al archivo donde tengo la clase ticket y el de la conexion a mi base de datos.

En el index llamo a una funcion dándole 2 parametros, el de conexión a mi base de datos y el que obtengo al loguearme para que busque en mi base de datos la suma de todos los campos que esten en el campo prioridad

```
$consulta2 = $ticket->ListGananciasCloseEmpleado($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
```

en mi funcion tengo lo siguiente

```
$consulta2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT SUM(recarga) as Total, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                                         FROM ticket as t
                                         JOIN usuario AS u
                                         ON t.id_usuario = u.id
                                         WHERE t.status = '3' AND t.id_usuario = ".$id."  AND t.fecha_creacion ='".$fecha."'") 
                                         or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta2;


}
```

obtengo NULL en la respuesta pero en mi base de datos si tengo el campo en mi bd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui muestro como estoy haciendo el fetch

```
 $fila=$consulta2->fetch_assoc(); 
 $TotalPrecios=$fila['Total'];   
 echo $TotalPrecios;
```

Trato de sumar todos los registros que haya en cada ticket ingresado esos 2 parametros, cuando hago la consulta en el phpmyadmin si me regresa el valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿en que estoy fallando exactamente?

Comment: ¿Qué tal si nos pasas unos registros de ejemplo en SQL e intentamos reproducir qué puede estar fallando para poder ayudarte? https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hay varias cosas que no cuadran. En primer lugar, la consulta de la captura de pantalla y la del código no son iguales, en la captura falta este criterio: `AND t.fecha_creacion ='".$fecha."'"`; Luego, ¿verificaste que la consulta se está creando bien, y que se reciben bien los valores que manejas en ella? Eso es fácil de comprobar guardando la consulta en una variable e imprimiéndola. También, no es buena idea devolver el recurso de la consulta para hacer el `fetch` en otro sitio... tampoco es claro en qué parte exactamente lo haces, no se sabe si la conexión o el recurso se cerraron ....

Comment: ... deberías trabajar el resultado y devolverlo desde la función. Es la manera en que se suelen tratar los resultados de consultas, en vez de hacer viajar el recurso de un lado para otro, obtén los datos en caliente. Y finalmente, considera usar consultas preparadas para blindar tu código contra ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Hola @JuanOrtiz, ¿has abandonado esta pregunta? Hemos quedado a la espera de que modifiques la pregunta, aportando más datos, para poder ayudarte